# Passing parameters to start as a console or GUI application?

Tags: c#

I have a console application that will be kicked off with a scheduler.  If for some reason, part of that file is not able to be built I need a GUI front end so we can run it the next day with specific input.

Is there as way pass parameters to the application entry point to start the console application or the GUI application based on the arguments passed.

Comment: See <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82838/how-to-read-commandline-parameters-in-console-application>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to either run as a console app or a windows app based on a commandline switch.

If you look at the last message in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/fd89cf64-eab4-4cc5-8f35-74ec848d8a60), Jeffrey Knight posted code to do what you are asking.

However, note that many "hybrid" apps actually ship two different executables (look at visual studio- devenv.exe is the gui, devenv.com is the console). Using a "hybrid" approach can sometimes lead to hard to track down issues.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Philip.  That is exactly what I am looking for.  I was unsure if this would even be a good practice or if I should use 2 different executables.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your main method (Program.cs). You'll put your logic there, and determine what to do , and conditionally execute Application.Run()

Answer (score 1):

I think Philip is right. Although I've been using the "hybrid" approach in a widely deployed commercial application without problems. I did have some issues with the "hybrid" code I started out with, so I ended up fixing them and re-releasing the solution.

So feel free to take advantage of it. It's actually quite simple to use. The [hybrid system](http://code.google.com/p/dualsubsystem/) is on google code and updates an old codeguru solution of this technique and provides the source code and working example binaries.

Comment: This should get a _lot_ more attention

Answer (score 0):

Write the GUI output to a file that the console app checks when loading.  This way your console app can do the repair operations and the normal operations in one scheduled operation.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this would be to have the console app write the config file for a GUI app (WinForms is simplest).

I like the Hybrid approach, the command line switch appears to be fluff.

It could be simpler to have two applications using the same engine for common functionality.  The way to think of it is the console app is for computers to use while the GUI App is for humans to use.  Since the CLI App will execute first then it can communicate it's data through the config file to the GUI App.

One side benefit would be the interface to the processing engine would be more concise thus easier to maintain in the future.

This would be the simplest, because the Config file mechanism is easily available and you do not have to write a bunch of formatting and parsing routines.

If you don't want to use the Config mechanism, you could directly write JSON or XML Serialization to a file to easily transfer data also