# Pass information from VBA to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vba

I'm trying to pass a string from a VBA application (running through MicroStation - CAD Draftiong Tool) to a VB.NET program but having some difficulty. I have found a couple of threads on here to do similar but mine doesn't seem to want to work.

The VBA part of the issue is here. This code came from another Stackoverflow thread asking a similar question to what i am.

```
    Dim strProgramName As String
    Dim strArgument As String

    strProgramName = HPDIR & "Utilities\HP_CheckForUpdates.exe"
    strArgument = "/ver=" & vVersion(0)

    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", vbNormalFocus)
```

My issue is how can i get my VB.NET program to read the argument above?
On another thread i found "Environemnt.GetCommandLineArgs", but mine always returns "System.String[]"

Essentially all i am trying to do is grab the string from VBA and display it in VB.NET. I am happy to hear of other / better ways to do it rather than arguments.

Comment: Maybe this question will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82838/best-way-to-read-commandline-parameters-in-console-application

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately it doesn't help me as the "GetCommandLineArgs" is always empty when the VB.NET program loads.

Comment: If you use this like in the link above: `Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)` then you don't need anything you mentioned, you have the command line arguments in the string array args()!

Comment: It still returns nothing. Is there another / better way to achieve this?

Comment: So you have the source code for `HP_CheckForUpdates.exe`? I suggest first simply testing that program alone with command line arguments. Take VBA out of the equation and establish that you can recognise command line arguments in .Net (it works for everyone else). Don't try and tack a bunch of stuff together and think it'll work - unit test each piece individually. Start with `HP_CheckForUpdates.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can send the command line params from one vb program to the other vb program

**Sender module:**

```
Module Module_Sender

    Sub Main()

        Dim strCommand As String
        strCommand = "CommandReciever.exe" + Space(1) + " ali"

        Console.WriteLine("Sending shell command ... ")

        Interaction.Shell(strCommand, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)

    End Sub

End Module
```

**Receiver Module:**

```
Module Module_Reciever

    Sub Main()
        Dim args() As String = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

        If (args.Length > 0) Then
            'display param And exit
            Console.WriteLine("Program param = " + args(1))
            Console.WriteLine("press enter key to exit ...")
            Console.Read()
            Return 'System.Environment.Exit(1);
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Hey, Program id param expected ...")
        End If


    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: You can test by placing both sender and receiver console app in same folder and run the sender, it will call the receiver and display the param it received from sender.